# pushing tableview results in cellForRowAtIndexPath exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to build a multilayer xmlparser which shows data in a tableview and switches to the next view based on the selected row (most likely to the same viewcontroller).

I started with storyboard segues but as i am using dynamic cells i dont know how to create more than one push segue (because it needs to push to various viewcontrollers). So i kept the storyboard views, deleted all the segues and used the code below instead.

however it throws this exception when the new view tries to pupulate the row:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource
>   must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"index: %i", indexPath.row);

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            DetailViewController *detailViewController = [DetailViewController alloc];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
            break;
        }
        //...
        default:
        {
            LayerViewController *layerViewController= [LayerViewController alloc];
            [layerViewController setStartUpWithIndex:indexPath.row andLayer:layercount];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:layerViewController animated:YES];
            break;
        }


    }

}
```

setStartUpWithIndex:andLayer: is my init method...

the problem does not occur when im pushing via storyboard segue with the following segue code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setStartUpWithIndex:indexPath.row andLayer:layercount];
}
```

i think i am missing something the "segue" method does which i need to include in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath as cellForRowAtIndexPath: works fine in the first layer of the view.

requested edit:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LayerCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"HerstellerName"];
//    cell.textLabel.text = @"ololol";

    return cell;
}
```

the articles array is working btw

Comment: The error is in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, you should show the code for it. Does it only occur if you select a row other than row 0, or row 0 or all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating any cells. I don't know why Apple didn't include this in the default implementation, but after:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You need to add:

```
if (cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Otherwise you're just relying on dequeued cells which won't exist when the tableView loads.

Edit: And if you're not using ARC, you need to wrap that alloc method with an autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing another viewController to be viewed and this next viewController has no dataSource methods implemented. This what happened.

As far as I understood, you are trying to present an xml node with a table in the way that each table row consist child nodes of presented node. selecting row with chld node gets you to next table view which presents table with child nodes of selected node.

IMO you may need only one view controller to present current xml node, which changes only data to be presented in a table and reloads the table again. So no pushing view controllers is needed. You can use then method

```
– reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

for all the nodes in the table, setting animation similar to changing view controller (aka sliding old table left)

Comment: i am pushing the same datacontroller....it is pushing itself. the reload thingy seems fine for some rows, but others need a whole new viewcontroller and i am getting the same error when i try to push to another (still quite similar) one

Comment: So the problem could be that you have the same instance of viewController which refers to the same table. You have to choose: reload table without pushing any viewController OR have two separate instances of view controller which are pushing each other. I would try to reload table though.

Comment: Does another view controller conforms to UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Comment: What does it mean that some rows need other view controller? Do you need few separate view controllers in one table?

Comment: no i meant that if u select the first it goes to another layer of the same tableviewcontroller, row 2-5 need another tableviewcontroller and mbe row 6 leads to a detailedviewcontroller, its custom and depends on the layer of the actual tableview